# Linear graph background

Tags: android

I have to create the linear graph with background...I am getting linear graph properly but not getting background.  Below is my code..[image]

I want graph like attached Image..

```
exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
                new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d), new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d),
                new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d), new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d) });

        graphView = new LineGraphView(this // context
                , "CoolingGraph" // heading
        );
        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data
        graphView.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] { "2 days ago",
                "yesterday", "today", "tomorrow" });
        graphView
                .setVerticalLabels(new String[] { "high", "middle", "low" });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the drawBackground property. 
From [LineGraphView documentation](http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html):

**LineGraphView drawBackground**
The LineGraphView has a special feature: drawBackground. This draws a light background under the diagram stroke.

and from the [Source code of LineGraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/com/jjoe64/graphview/LineGraphView.java):

```
@Override
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
    paintBackground.setColor(color);
}

/**
 * @param drawBackground true for a light blue background under the graph line
 */
public void setDrawBackground(boolean drawBackground) {
    this.drawBackground = drawBackground;
}
```

Other way to do it is to draw the graph yourself using Android `Paint` and then you can easily draw the background (by setting the paint style to `FILL_AND_STROKE`.
Besides the background, you will have a better control over the look and feel of your graph if you'll implement it this way.

Some links to get you started:

- Simple Graph drawing tutorial: [Creating custom Android views](http://www.jayway.com/2012/07/03/creating-custom-android-views-part-2-how-padding-works-and-how-to-draw-your-own-content/)
- About paint fill and stroke style: [Paint style - fill and stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723545/whats-the-point-of-fill-and-stroke)

Comment: hello Daniel, I am also referring same link..and getting the linear graph as required but I tried all background functions but not succeed.

Comment: Yes they r using:   paintBackground = new Paint();
  paintBackground.setColor(Color.rgb(20, 40, 60));
  paintBackground.setStrokeWidth(4);